# What's the best conditional formula when there are lots of conditions in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Column A on my data set there are group identification numbers. They are integers ranging from 0 to 30.

In Column B is my data.

The groups form 10 cohorts, and the cohorts don't map onto the group number in any clear way. In Column C I want to create a cohort number. For example, groups 2, 4 and 24 constitute cohort 1. Groups 1, 11, and 30 constitute cohort 2, and so on.

Here's what the first 10 rows look like.

[image: Example of first 10 rows]

What's the best formula to use? I get that something like =IF(A1=1,1,IF(A1=2,1,IF(A1=3,3,IF(A1=4,1)))) ...and so on will work, but it would be very tedious to write. Can I cover all the possibilities with a single formula?

Comment: Is it always three groups per cohort?  Every group is in exactly one cohort?  Do the group identification, cohort identification or group assignment to cohort ever change?  If everything is static, you might as well just enter the values in column C because you would do more work creating formulas.  If it's not static, you don't want to hard code formulas; use a lookup table, instead (cohort IDs as column headings, members in each column).  Each C cell finds its col A value in the table and returns the column heading.

Comment: Keep in mind that a table just relocates what you need in column C.  If you have to create the table and create the formulas to lookup the values in the table, you might as well just make column C your table.

Comment: Every group is in exactly one cohort. It's not always three groups per cohort. It is static, but there are hundreds of rows.

Comment: I was going to suggest `=IF(OR(A1=2,A1=4,A1=24),1,IF(OR(A1=1,A1=11,A1=30),2,...` based on what you had said before the edit. You also say that 2,4 and 24 constitute cohort 1. However I also see that if a1=4 that is cohort 4, in that case what I have won't work.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I've fixed that now.

Comment: So the rows represent individuals and each individual is in one of 30 groups?  Using a table of group to cohort assignments would be the way to go.  Each column C entry would be a lookup formula.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, VLOOKUP would be the way to go on a problem like this, and @mtone's answer describes that.  It just happens that your data allows what might be an even simpler solution that doesn't require a table.  The CHOOSE function picks a value from a list and your group "names" are perfectly suited to use as the index.  You would build the list once inside the first formula and then copy it down the column.  So say row 1 is the first data row.  Cell C1 would be:

```
    =CHOOSE(A1+1,a,b,c,d,e,...)
```

The pointer needs to start with 1 (first value in the list), so the "A1+1", which will then run from 1 to 31.  The "a,b,c,..." is the list of cohort numbers assigned to the values in column A, in order.  So "a" would be the cohort associated with group 0, "b" would be the cohort associated with group 1, etc.  The CHOOSE function just selects the nth value from the list based on the index (the first term), so this functions as your lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

How is it determined which group belong to what cohort? If it is predetermined, you could enter those in another table (with columns: group, cohort with a row for each group) and then the formula in C would use VLOOKUP to fetch the correct cohort for that group.

VLOOKUP could essential do this: Let's do A. Ok this is group 4, let's check in that other table what cohort group 4 belongs in, and write that in C. Repeat for B. etc.

The idea is not include in your formula something that varies, and use another table for that instead.

Comment: It is predetermined. Would a lookup table be something I create in a separate sheet in the Excel file?

Comment: You could do it in another location on the same sheet.  Doing it on another sheet just requires adding the sheet identification to each cell reference.

Comment: A lookup table can reside in another excel file, another sheet within the file, or in the same sheet (as @fixer1234 suggests). It is up to you to decide. Personally I prefer another sheet in the file, since deleting rows from your table doesn't risk deleting rows from the lookup table.